# Can I easily access the next iteration without using `foreach' in c#?

Tags: c#, iterator

I have a C# Collection and I was wondering if it was possible to access the next yielded value similar to what is possible using Python's `.next()` method. e.g.

```
 double diffFoo = myList.next() - myObject.Foo;
 double diffBar = myList.next() - myObject.Bar;
 ...
```

Instead of,

```
 double diffFoo = myList[0] - myObject.Foo;
 double diffBar = myList[1] - myObject.Bar;
 ...
```

In this case a `foreach` loop is not appropriate since a different class method is used on each 'iteration'. I would like to do this to save having to keep updated the indexes if/when the order needs to change in the code.

Comment: Yes but you would probably end up using a `while loop` along with the `GetEnumerator` Method, then using the .MoveNext() method would you like an example..?

Comment: What is the REAL business problem that this proposed solution addresses?

Comment: @Pieter The use is for defining a bunch of classes to read different .csv files which have similar columns but ordered differently. Using the iterator method I can cut and paste into a new class and swap/add/remove lines until they match. Without iterators I would also have to set the indices, which is time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the enumerator from the list if you prefer:

```
var s = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };
var enumerator = s.GetEnumerator();
enumerator.MoveNext();
Debug.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
enumerator.MoveNext();
Debug.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
```

Comment: Just a caveat - this works apart from I had to put a `.Cast<string>()` in there when obtaining an enumerator from a `string[]` so that the results were not generic objects. (I realise that the question implies a generic list but in my actual code it is a string array).

Answer (score 2):

Don't overlook the low-tech solution:

```
int index = 0;
double diffFoo = myList[index++] - myObject.Foo;
double diffBar = myList[index++] - myObject.Bar;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [IEnumerator.MoveNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext.aspx) method.

```
var enumerator = myList.GetEnumerator();

enumerator.MoveNext();
double diffFoo = enumerator.Current - myObject.Foo;

enumerator.MoveNext();
double diffBar =enumerator.Current - myObject.Bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

The IEnumerator interface provides a method called GetNext(). You can obtain the next item from the collection. There is also the Generic version of IEnumerator: IEnumerator, See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx).

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerable<T>` and [**`IEnumerator`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx) interfaces. They are used by `foreach` loop.

You can call `GetEnumerator` on collection to get enumerator instance. With that you can use `MoveNext()` method and `Current` property.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work

```
var someEnumerator = getInt().GetEnumerator();
while(someEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    int intEnumerate = someEnumerator.Current;
    Console.WriteLine(intEnumerate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Python but it exist in c# now!

Any object implements IEnumerable supports this feature.

Have a look yield operator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0(v=vs.80).aspx